# C#: Method to add two 1-D arrays error "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#

I am adding two 1-D arrays but I am getting an error in the code I have written:
Error: There are unhandled exceptions in the code.

```
static void Main()
{
 // setup two test arrays

 int[] x = new int[] { 2, 4, 6 };
 int[] y = new int[] { 3, 6, 9 };

 // invoke method and store result

int[] z = AddVectors(x, y);

}
static int[] AddVectors(int[] a, int[] b)
{

 // check that both arrays are of the same length

 if(a.Length == b.Length ) return null;

 // create a new array to store result

 int[] c = new int[a.Length];

 // carry out addition term by term

 for (int i = 0; i <= c.Length; i++)
 {
     c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
 }

 // return resulting array

  return c;
 }
}
```

Comment: Title says you're getting compile time error, but question itself talks about exceptions. What exactly is happening?

Comment: Downvoted: either it's a compile error or an unhandled exception.

Comment: You're correct it is an unhandled exception. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You should check that:

```
if(a.Length != b.Length ) return null;
```

PS: try stating more concisely and clearly what your question is.

Comment: Aww, you beat me to it.

Comment: The error "Unhandled exceptions" still arises though?

Comment: OK I will take that on board from now on.

Comment: @NoviceCoder2 if this solves your question please mark it as an answer.

Comment: It does not fully solve it. There were two errors and this was one. The other is that when the code runs an error occurs "Unhandled Exceptions"

Comment: Can you provide an code snippet of how you are using this code further? Most likely is because "z" is null and you are using it afterwards. I don't get any other errors.